# Is my US Drivers License valid to board an airplane?

Tags: usa, domestic-travel, real-id

In May, I received a new Minnesota State Drivers license. This Driver's license is *not* a Real ID, and is marked with `NOT FOR FEDERAL IDENTIFICATION`. According to [TSA RealID Info](https://www.tsa.gov/real-id) I believe that this License is valid to be used as identification until 2023.

If I go to a US-Domestic airport, will this Identification be accepted?

How would I find out for sure?

(Background, I also need to renew my passport which is my primary form of identification when boarding a plane. I would like to renew it soon, but then I won't have it for my next few flights that are coming up).

Comment: What state are you in?  You don't have a US driver's license- you have a state driver's license, and not all states create them equally

Comment: @CarlKevinson He's from Minnesota. From various online articles, including mn.gov, their licenses can be used to board flights until May 2023.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, your ID is valid for domestic travel within the US — for now.

The REAL ID requirement has been once again pushed back, and now will not come into effect until (at least) May 3, 2023.  From that date you will require* either a REAL ID compliant ID (which yours is not), or a passport in order to travel, but, until then, your new Drivers License is fine.

* With exceptions, such as for passengers too young to have suitable ID, etc.

Comment: Given how many times the deadline has been extended, I have *very* serious doubts that it will actually happen in 2023.

Comment: or any of the IDs on [this list](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification), including green cards, EADs, military IDs, etc.

Comment: @JonathanReez I'm all for the current date.  My current (non-REAL ID) drivers license expires literally the day before the current start date!

Comment: @Doc - I got my current (10 year validity) shortly before RealID was announced, and was irritated that I would have to spend extra money to get a Real one before it expired. Well, not an issue anymore - I’ll get a RealID one when my current one expires before the current deadline… Whether it gets extended again or not no longer matters.

Comment: The deadline is now extended to May 7, 2025.